# Can I move a wildcard after melding if I get 3 natural cards in canasta?

Tags: canasta

Can I move wildcards around, from set to set, to build a canasta?

Answer (score 2):

No.

There is no specific rule that I can point to in the various online resources I know to quote; but there is nothing in the rules that says that this would be allowed.

You can add additional cards from your hand to an existing meld; if the rules intended for you to be able to move or remove cards from a meld they would list that as an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the rules for melding once a card is in a meld it cannot be picked back up with one exception for a meld that was played this turn which comes with penaltiess.

[Rules](http://www.canasta.net/canasta_rules.php)

> After drawing a card, a player may meld cards if (s)he wants to. Cards are melded in columns of at least three cards; e.g. you can meld three Kings, or four Fives. You cannot meld sequences like Four-Five-Six. Once a card has been melded, it cannot be taken back into the hand (except with the Undo meld option).

Note that the rules show a big advantage from not playing wild cards in your melds when possible.

> A mixed canasta is worth 300 points, a natural canasta 500 points, and a wildcard canasta 1,000 points.

Comment: I have never heard of a wildcard Canasta; that sounds like something unique to that online implementation. By normal rules; a Meld could never be all wildcards.

Comment: @GendoIkari search for Wild Card Melds on [this page](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#classic-variations) for example rules. I've played this type of canasta many years ago. It is most certainly not specific to the online implementation.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Interesting, thanks. But it is a variant, not regular rules.